# Banach spaces admitting a coarser topology for which the closed unit ball is compact.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces, weak-topology, reflexive-space

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $B$ be its closed unit ball.

It is well known that $B$  is compact in the weak topology provided $B$ is reflexive.   Otherwise,   if $X$ is at least
a  dual space, then $B$ is compact in the weak* topology.

These examples show that, in many situations, there exists a Hausdorff locally convex topology on $X$, coarser than the
norm topology,  relative to which
$B$ is compact.

For $X=c_0$, I cannot think of such a topology and I doubt it exists.  The reason is I feel the sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ given
by
$$
  x_n= (1,1,\ldots, 1,0,0, 0\ldots)
  $$
($n$ ones) cannot possibly have a cluster point in any sensible topology.

**Question**.  Given a Banach space $X$,  is there always  a Hausdorff locally convex topology on $X$, coarser than the
norm topology, relative to which the
closed unit ball is compact? Can one characterize the spaces for which this is true?
What if $X=c_0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an old result of K.F. Ng [On a theorem of Dixmier, Math. Scand. 29 (1971), 279–280 (1972)] that a Banach space $X$ whose unit ball $B$ is compact in some coarser locally convex topology $\tau$ is a dual Banach space. Namely, it is the dual of $Y=\{f\in X^*: f|_B$ is $\tau$-continuous$\}$ endowed with the dual norm.

Answer (score 4):

[Krein–Milman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Milman_theorem) — A compact convex subset of a Hausdorff locally convex topological vector space is equal to the closed convex hull of its extreme points.

Since the unit ball of $c_0$ has no extreme points, we are done.

Comment: Good thinking!  I feel like accepting your answer but I'll wait a while to see if my question about characterization of these spaces gets answered.  Any ideas? Obviously the unit ball must have plenty exteme points, but exactly how much?